# Convert dask dataframe to avro

Tags: python, avro, dask

I have a dask dataframe with 100 partitions and 57 columns. I want to save it then as avro on Google Cloud Storage. I have checked the [`intake-avro` lib](https://intake-avro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but it only can convert avro to dask dataframes and not viceversa.

Is there any lib out there to do this or should I write my own? I want to make sure I don't reinvent wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, intake-avro (and other intake drivers) are concerned with format/service -> familiar container, and not with output.

Avro is not, generally speaking, a columnar format, and so to write it with Dask, you need a `bag`, not a `dataframe`. You will want to do:

```
df.to_bag().to_avro(...)
```

(see the [docs](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.Bag.to_avro))

Unfortunately, you will need to construct your own schema JSON object, which should be fairly easy from the original dataframe's dtypes.

The library that intake-avro and Dask use for fast reading of avro to dataframes, [uavro](https://github.com/martindurant/uavro), may at some point be extended to write too.

Comment: thanks that's really helpful. do you know if dask hhas a function to create json schema?

Comment: It does not. I don't know if there is some other place you could get this, but would not be hard to write.